# iteration through nested Dictionary and printing in Django html page

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops

I Have a Dictionary like this

```
mainDict={'RA CROXE-16353': 
 {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Leela', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  Rainbow when it is conversation with external',      'BINARIES': 'SYM'},  
'RA CROXE-16344': 
{'ENGINEER_NAME': 'MARK', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Network SIP ISDN TLS call with VPN_G729', 'BINARIES': 'TEL.1.so'}
     }
```

I want to iterate through the dictionary so that I can print in the Table Format in Django.

```
CR              ENGINEER_NAME     DESCRIPTION                                        BINARIES

RA CROXE-16353  Leela             M5  Rainbow when it is conversation with external  SYM
RA CROXE-16344  MARK              M5 Network SIP ISDN TLS call with VPN_G729         TEL.1.so
```

Please, anyone, let me know how to proceed

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>CR</td>
        <td>Engineer Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Binaries</td>
    </tr>
    {% for key,value in mainDict.items %}
        {% for k,val in value.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}<td>         
        <td> {{ value }} </td>      
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

I have tried to loop over the code with keys and values but I am unable to print in the required format.

Comment: @Hermant Can I see your views.py file please...have you passed in mainDict to the template's rendered context?

Comment: mainDict={}
     for i in range(0,len(ID_DDTS_CR2)):
      subDict=    {columns[0]:ENGINEER_NAME2[i],columns[1]:DESCRIPTION2[i],columns[2]:BINARIES2[i]}
  mainDict[ID_DDTS_CR2[i]]=subDict
 print("Main Dict",mainDict)
 
            args = {
   'mainDict':mainDict,
   'EngName':ENGINEER_NAME2,
   'Desc':DESCRIPTION2,
   'Bin':BINARIES2,
   'CR':ID_DDTS_CR2
 }
     return render(request,'JournalContent/test.html',args)

Comment: Could you add this to the question please :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to start with is a structure like this in your `views.py` template function, which can then be `looped` much easier on the template side:

```
CRS = [
    {
          'CR': 'RA CROXE-16344'
          'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Leela', 
          'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  Rainbow when it is conversation with external',
          'BINARIES': 'SYM'
    },
    {  
          'CR': 'RA CROXE-16344'
          'ENGINEER_NAME': 'MARK', 
          'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Network SIP ISDN TLS call with VPN_G729', 
          'BINARIES': 'TEL.1.so'
    }
]
```

So, something like this in `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader


def index(request):
    CRS = [
        {
           'CR': 'RA CROXE-16344'
           'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Leela', 
           'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  Rainbow when it is conversation with external',
           'BINARIES': 'SYM'
        },
        {   
           'CR': 'RA CROXE-16344'
           'ENGINEER_NAME': 'MARK', 
           'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Network SIP ISDN TLS call with VPN_G729', 
           'BINARIES': 'TEL.1.so'
        }
    ]
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
        'CRS': CRS,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And the run with the following:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>CR</td>
        <td>Engineer Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Binaries</td>
    </tr>
    {% for CR in CRS %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ CR.CR }}<td>         
        <td>{{ CR.ENGINEEER_NAME }}</td>
        <td>{{ CR.DESCRIPTION }}</td>
        <td>{{ CR.BINARIES }}</td>      
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: a = ['RA CROXE-14156', 'RA CROXE-14084']
b = ['ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION','BINARIES','CR']
c = ['Kishore Kumar KRISHNAMURTHY', 'Delica JESLYN', 'Deebika SRINIVASAN']
d = ['M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu', 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-13200 error is thrown when execute the user Memory re-initialization comment', '[Related] : CH - M4: Avoid reboot for desk-sharing logon/logoff- Disable the feature']
e=['TEL', 'mao.SYM', 'TEL.1.so'] I have four lists how can I form like you got dictionary

Comment: @HemantChowdary I think what I am essentially saying is that the data structure you currently have for mainDict is a little awkward to loop over in a table format...if you can sort the data structure to be similar to the above, then you will find it much easier to loop in a table format, essentiay, making each element of the `CRS = []` list a row in the table...does that make sense?

Comment: @HemantChowdary It looks to me like if you understand how those four lists can be maniuplated into the one list, then you will be good to go... if you could, contact me in the chat and I will try to help where I can.

Comment: Twitter: @michealjroberts